# pybind11 for C++14/C++17

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-python, pybind11

Does pybind11 work for C++14 and C++17 seamlessly ?

I'm planning to use Boost.python for my project which is currently in C++11. In future I may have to upgrade to C++14 or C++17. So I wanted to understand what will be the right choice here - boost.python ot pybind11.

From pybind11 doc, it says - "seamless operability between C++11 and Python" So bit confused

Comment: I would assume that it needs 11 at a minimum but just works with later editions.

Comment: I'm confused to decide between boost.python and pybind11. Can you help

Comment: How? You haven't told us what your requirements are beyond "must work with c++14 or c++17". I would assume both will work, so that is not a valid decision point.

Comment: It already supports some of C++17 new features: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#c-17-library-containers; Anyway, C++ standards are generally backward compatible

Comment: @Botje I have a c++ library (subscribes to a middleware, receives updates and deserialize the data). I have to write a python wrapper over it to be used by python clients.

Comment: @botje Creating a pure virtual class in C++ and having its implementation in python, passing this object as a param to C++ class etcs are my use cases which works with Boost.python. Not sure if this will work in pybind11

Comment: Seems like you have already figured out which library to use.

Comment: No, I am just evaluating if these things are possible. I got to know everything is possible using Boost.python and yet to do in pybind11. I believe these are supported in pybind11 too

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it works with C++11/14/17/20, see [corresponding section](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#configuration-variables) in docs.

> By default, pybind11 will compile modules with the compiler default or the minimum standard required by pybind11, whichever is higher.

Comment: What an unfortunate naming choice... perhaps they should rebrand as pybindcpp